# rails expire_page is not deleting the cached file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller action that has page caching, and I made a sweeper that calls expire_page with the controller and the action specified...

The controller action renders a js.erb template, so I am trying to ensure that expire_page deletes the .js file in public/javascripts, which it is not doing.

```
class JavascriptsController < ApplicationController

  caches_page :lol

  def lol
    @lol = Lol.all
  end

end

class LolSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Lol

  def after_create(lol)
    puts "lol!!!!!!!"
    expire_page(:controller => "javascripts", :action => "lol", :format => 'js')
  end

end
```

... So, I visit javascripts/lol.js and I get my template rendered..  I verified that public/javascripts/lol.js exists...  I then create a new Lol record, and I see "lol!!!!!!!!!" meaning the after_create observer method is triggered, but expire_page is doing nothing...

Comment: I am sure it's not justified, but all those "lol's" make me not want to analyse that code.

Comment: come on...  who doesn't love a good lol?  it's not like that is a lot of code to analyze anyway!

Comment: what if you explicitly give the path : expire_page "javascripts/lol.js"

Comment: I don't know your project, but it is quite wierd to name a controller Javascript, as the route is the same as the static assets... (Best practices require application javascript goes in static assets path, and resource related javascript to js format of corresponding controller)

Comment: The point of the javascripts controller is to be able to do javascript_tag "<some controller action>", and have the javascripts controller dynamically generate JS for that view.

Comment: What does work is to put this in my sweeper after_create:  File.delete(File.expand_path("#{Rails.root}/public/javascripts/lol.js"))...  But, I really don't think I should have to do that.

Answer (score 2):

According to RailsGuides: 'Page caching ignores all parameters.' I think I had similar problem while working on cashing `.xml` responses: I would write the cache for `/lol.xml`, but was trying to expire cache for `/lol` (`write` and `expire` operations can be seen in the server log). The way I made it work: I made the cache "format-agnostic" like this:

```
cashes_page :lol, :cache_path => Proc.new { |controller| controller.params.delete_if {|k,v| k == "format"} }
```

and expire in the sweeper like this:

```
expire_page(:controller => "javascripts", :action => "lol")
```

It solved my problem. Also, as a note, shouldn't your `lol` action be called `lols`? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solution form Simon's answer and it didn't work for me. The solution that worked was:

```
expire_page('javascripts/lol.js')
```